# continue fetching data from service in background

Tags: ios, background

I am calling webservice in foregroud while the downloading is in progress, I press home button (app is in background now), I want to continue the fetching/downloading in background and complete it, is this possible in iOS? if yes then how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and the problem you're facing. Don't ask others for the code.

Comment: Sorry i cant post the code here, but you can consider it as any rest API call from which we download json data, while the downloading is in progress press home button, i want the download should continue in background.

Comment: It depends how long it will take.  If the download is less than 3 minutes, then you can call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to continue working in the background, but after 3 minutes your app will be suspended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below code in applicationDidEnterBackground appdelegate method and it works for me.

```
UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;

bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ 
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `URLSessionDownloadTask` for downloading any data in the background and enable `Background fetch` under the background modes in capabilities.

[image: Background Fetch]

For more info please refer, 
[Downloading files in background](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/networking/urlsession-background-downloads/)